# Converting a Matrix to a grid of colors

Tags: c#, colors, matrix, console-application, converters

I'm currently making a console application in C# (will be going to a Windows Form application in the future.  Sooner if needed).  My current objective is to have a matrix (current size 52x42) be exported as an image (bitmap, jpeg, png, I'm flexible) where each value in the matrix (0, 1, 2, 3) is portrayed as a white, black, blue, or red square of size 20px x 20px with a grid 1px wide seperating each 'cell'.

Can this even be done in a console application, and if so how?  If not, what would I need to get it working in a Windows Form application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a 52x42-px bitmap and fill it using colours corresponding to your matrix values.

```
using System.Drawing;

void SaveMatrixAsImage(Matrix mat, string path)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(mat.ColumnCount, mat.RowCount))
    {
        for (int r = 0; r != mat.RowCount;    ++r)
        for (int c = 0; c != mat.ColumnCount; ++c)
            bmp.SetPixel(c, r, MakeMatrixColor(mat[r, c]));
        bmp.Save(path);
    }
}

Color MakeMatrixColor(int n)
{
    switch (n)
    {
        case 0: return Color.White;
        case 1: return Color.Black;
        case 2: return Color.Blue;
        case 3: return Color.Red;
    }
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It took a little tweaking to get everything to fit in my project, but I learned quite a bit in the process, and these code segments are incredibly useful =)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `Graphics` object that allows you to draw shapes like lines and rectangles. This is faster than drawing single pixels

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(mat.ColumnCount, mat.RowCount)) {
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        ....
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 20, 20);
        ....
    }
}
bmp.Save(...);
```